# Is there a way to fire an event when the contents of an EditText view have changed?

Tags: android, user-interface

I can see keys on the device fire for a particular `View` with `onKey`, but this doesn't fire when keys on the `software keyboard` are pressed.

I am trying to build a dynamic `UI` that recalculates a value as the input changes, while it's changing.

Is there a way to capture either that the value of the `EditText` has changed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yeah, you just need to add a TextChangedListener:

```
textEdit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable)
        {
            // Do Stuff

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence text, int start, int count, int after)
        {
            // Do Stuff

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int start, int before, int count)
        {
            // Do Stuff

        }

    });
```

You can find more info here:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html

Answer (score 1):

Per: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html

```
    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void onTextChanged (CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }
        public void afterTextChanged (Editable s) {

        }
        public void beforeTextChanged (CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }
    });
```