# Monitor the changes of a EditText

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to fire an event when the contents of an EditText view have changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949116/is-there-a-way-to-fire-an-event-when-the-contents-of-an-edittext-view-have-chang)

I'd like to listen when the user changes a edit text in order to formatting it. Is there some kind of listener or interface I can use for that? Thanks

Comment: Do you mean, text change listener for an EditText?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you're looking for is probably a `TextWatcher`, check this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) for more information. Here's how to implement it:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
});
```