# Android - Modify entered text before it reaches EditText View

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-input-method

**Problem Statement :**

We have a requirement to kind of hack the user input ( before it reaches EditText ) and trigger some functionality BEFORE the text reaches the EditText View

How can this be done ??

**Attempted solutions :**

a. Tried onKeyPreIme() method in the View and the Layout - Does NOT work

b. I am assuming the listeners on the EditText will be called AFTER the text reaches the view. Hence does NOT support my solution approach.

c. Tried dispatchKeyEventPreIme() method in the View and the Layout - Does NOT work.

---

Can I use BaseInputConnection or other such class ? If so, how ?
Essentially, what will be a good approach to this solution ?

Comment: Can you elaborate your problem a little more?

Comment: i hope this help you ! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8437975/monitor-the-changes-of-a-edittext

Comment: @RahulChandrabhan - We have a card swipe machine. Once the card is swiped, we want to change some portions of the card number BEFORE the numbers reach the application. Changing the text AFTER it reaches the View or Layout is always an option ... but not a safe one in our case. So - we want a solution that does NOT depend on the view.

Comment: @kdblue - The solution is the same as mentioned by Yossi below. As i understand, the listener design pattern triggers the listeners AFTER the data has been received by the Object. In my case I want to intercept the data BEFORE it reaches the object.

Comment: Can we customize or use an InputConnection ?

Answer (score 2):

use TextWatcher

```
your_edit_text.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            if (editable.toString().equals("anything_you_want")) {
                your_edit_text.setText("");
                // do something...
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: s i understand, the listener design pattern triggers the listeners AFTER the data has been received by the Object. In my case I want to intercept the data BEFORE it reaches the object.